# Changing status of Payment by Check orders does not properly trigger events

Tags: cartthrob, status, payment-gateway

We need to be able to accommodate payments by checks for our commercial customers, and have found that changing the status of orders placed through the Pay by Check gateway does not trigger normal events, such as updating inventory counts or logging items in the Purchased Items channel (both of which, by the way, work for normal credit card processing through Stripe).

Currently, on the Orders settings pane, both the Order Status and Purchased Items Channel sections are configured to use the same statuses for **Payment authorized/complete** (Paid) and **Payment being processed** (Awaiting Payment).

Also, on the Payments settings pane, the Pay By Check gateway **When order is taken, set processing status to** option is set to "Processing".

So, for example, once an order is placed on the front-end of the site, the order appears in the Orders channel with the status of Awaiting Payment. If I update the status to Paid, the order does trigger any of the actions that it should as a completed order. I've tried updating the status directly in the Orders channel as well as in the Ecommerce Orders Manager. Neither work. Also, I've tried using the `force_processing="yes"` parameter on the checkout form.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the status in EE's backend will not run any of those actions. At present there is no method to do what you request through changing EE's statuses.

The status itself is currently incidental to the payment collection system. The statuses are changed by outside actions, but changing the statuses manually won't reciprocally initiate those actions.

An extension or modification could be built to "complete" the transaction based on the status change, but at present we don't have anything in place to handle this.

Comment: Would it not make sense to be able to change a orders status this via the CT Order Manager and have it trigger those events? Sounds like a pretty important feature to implement to me?

Comment: It would make sense. And yes, every feature is important to someone. And I'm not making light of this particular item, but it's all just a question of timing. John, Since you have the inside track feel free to hound us on this feature if you so choose.

Comment: Yeah, i think i will do on this one :)